# Add margin between mini cart buttons

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added smart paypal button to my woocommerce store. Now the problem is this yellow paypal button do not have spacing with other buttons in my mini cart. You can look this at after adding one product to cart:
https://combosports.com/kimurawear-aspire-womens-sparring-kit/

You will see that the smart button is attached with the button above it. I want some margin in it but I could not find any way to add it.

The second thing is that the paypal yellow button on the right side of the product just below the add to cart button overrides everything. When I scroll down this yellow button breaks the header and everything. You can also see this on the link above. I am using this plugin for this yellow button:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/

Please help me in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1). For the first problem, I think you just need to use a better selector to override the style

```
.woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons.buttons.wcppec-cart-widget-spb {
    margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

2). For the second problem, you can add this selector to your custom css file.

The initial problem is, that for the iframe you have set: "z-index: 100;". You should change that to "z-index: 1;"

```
#woo_pp_ec_button_product .zoid-outlet .zoid-component-frame.zoid-visible {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My first problem has been solved through your answer. But the second answer does not work. It work when we initially scroll down but when we scroll up then it overrides again to header. Please check this out. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Please try the new selector, it should work now. I chose a dynamic ID before, so the ID changed & selector no longer work

Comment: I have contacted with the plugin support and they give me this code:
.zoid-outlet {
    z-index: 1;
}
And this worked for me. Thank you for your support also.

Comment: That's a better selector. I should have thought of that.

Comment: I have also asked another question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002539/how-to-change-the-phone-field-in-checkout-page-as-required
Can you answer this question also.