# How to change the phone field in checkout page as mandatory

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have checkout page in woocommerce at the following link:
https://combosports.com/checkout/

Now the problem is I want the phone field to be marked as required as other fields. How can I make this phone field mandatory. I have tried through the theme options but it does not work through it. I also want the optional text removed from the field and add asterisk mark on it. Please tell me how can I do that. Thank you in advance.

[This is the pic of phone field I have marked as required in theme options but it does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yP0o.png)

[Full page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1sDV.png)

Comment: Are you currently use the theme option?

Comment: I have marked my this phone field as required in my theme options but I don't know why it is not appearing in the checkout page.

Comment: I have added a pic of that phone field that is in my theme options.

Comment: can you take  a picture of whole  page instead? It's been long since I work with Woocommerce, so I cannot remember whole form

Comment: I have added a full page pic

Comment: Can you try reload page with Ctrl + F5 & disable cache on Network tab of Inspector. I saw it's a required field now after doing that. May you have some page caching?